# D Language Mango compilation error ( Windows environment )

Tags: makefile, d, dmd

I tried to install Mango and I found that it requires ldc. the 
makefile for Mango is from
[makefile](http://svn.dsource.org/projects/mango/trunk/mango/build/ldc/makefile)

I tried to install ldc on Windows but it doesn't go very smooth 
for the whole weekend, so I decide to try to install Mango with 
DMD.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I think mango is really old and requires the tango lib and a ldc version 1 compiler...

Comment: Is is possible to modify Mango to D2 or make it to compile by DMD?
I tried LDC, and it is very difficult to set it up on Windows environment.

Comment: I don't know, I know almost nothing about it.

Comment: I'm now trying to convert mango from D1 to D2. I will post the code once I'm done.